# What does "abd shell cmd" stand for?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

What does `cmd` in `abd shell cmd` stand for? The `cmd` command has to do with services running on the Android phone. What does the name `cmd` mean?

```
star2qltechn:/ $ cmd
cmd: No service specified; use -l to list all services
star2qltechn:/ $ cmd -l
Currently running services:
  AAS
  ...
```

Usually "cmd" stands for command but I don't understand how that makes sense. Calling a command "command" is not very specific about its functionality. It doesn't really differentiate it from any of the other commands since that name could apply to all commands. Also it doesn't have to do anything with services, which this `cmd` seems to deal with.

Comment: `cmd` is a generic front end to other **sub-commands**